# Issues starting Nessus in Kali Linux from WSL2

Tags: kali-linux, wsl2, systemctl

I am trying to install nessus for a vulnerability study in Kali linux. Kali is running as a Win-Kex instance from WSL2 on windows 11. I have downloaded Nessus and trying to install with:

```
sudo dpkg -i Nessus-10.1.2-debian6_amd64.deb
```

But I am getting error as ...

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate
```

Full error is:

```
[sudo] password for kali: 
(Reading database ... 189342 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack Nessus-10.1.2-debian6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nessus (10.1.2) over (10.1.2) ...
Setting up nessus (10.1.2) ...
Unpacking Nessus Scanner Core Components...
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

 - You can start Nessus Scanner by typing /bin/systemctl start nessusd.service
 - Then go to https://CLI-WIN-001:8834/ to configure your scanner
```

I tried to start the service from prompt, but same error:

```
$ /bin/systemctl start nessusd.service 
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

I tried to start the service using service command but got error there as well as nessusd service not found.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Perhaps see if this Tenable article helps.   https://www.tenable.com/blog/getting-started-with-nessus-on-kali-linux

Comment: it is not , /etc/init.d/nessusd , NO such file or directory .  the dpktg command is trying to install this as a service and failed in WSL2 . It may work in kali standalone installations

Comment: Maybe try a full install of Kali (using that here). Kali is not a friendly system and was not suited to WSL when I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to install nessus for a vulnerability study in Kali linux

First (before we cover the installation problem), this is probably not a good idea unless you are well aware of and okay with the limitations.  As you can tell if you look at my profile, I answer a lot of WSL questions - I think it's great overall.  But this is one area where it is typically *not* a good option.

The networking in WSL2 is NAT'd *behind*/inside the Windows host.  It is *not* bridged directly to the physical network.  As a result, you will only have layer 3 access to any network outside WSL2, greatly hindering the use of vulnerability tools.

A virtual machine *is* a better option in this case.

Side note:  There are improvements in the WSL2 networking area that are in preview right now.  If you are on Windows 11 Pro/Education or higher, then you can install the WSL Preview available in the Microsoft Store and follow the instructions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/swfyf7/bridged_networking_under_wsl_nonkluge/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) to turn on bridged networking.  Your results may vary.  Batteries not included.  Etc.

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.

The core problem is that WSL doesn't use Systemd, even in distributions where it is the default. Instead, WSL currently uses its own /init process as PID 1, which performs a few WSL-specific tasks that I mention in this answer (so I won't repeat them here).

In other words, without additional effort, Systemd (and thus `systemctl`) does not work on WSL.

From the looks of it in [the Nessus doc](https://docs.tenable.com/nessus/Content/NessusNonPrivilegedLinuxInitd.htm), Nessus does provide a SysVInit-style script in `/etc/init.d/nessusd`.  If this is the case for the Debian package, then you should be able to start it via:

```
sudo service nessusd start
```

If that does not work (and from the comments, it seems it may not), then you still have a few options:

- Look for the Systemd unit files for Nessus and determine how it is supposed to be started.  See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986) for an example of how to do this with a simple service.
- Or (and I don't really recommend this unless you really know what you are doing) enable Systemd in WSL, either manually or using one of the helper apps out there (also linked in the Ask Ubuntu answer above).

Comment: sudo service nessusd start -> this also didnot work. But I was able to start it  using  sudo /opt/nessus/sbin/nessus-service . Only problem is that it is not started as a service and attached to the terminal .but works well for the purpose

Answer (score 1):

I was able to start Nessus by the following command in Kali WSL:

```
sudo /opt/nessus/sbin/nessus-service
```

Then the service was reachable under URL `https://<IP of WSL>:8834`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is due to WSL2 not really "booting up" linux, instead Linux behaves more like a Docker container, without any sort of init system.

Mayb using a VM instead will help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).